# working with array of promises that have promises inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

Im doing the following code:

```
let promises = []
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
  promises.push(
    promiseFunction()
    .then((postCounters) => {
      promiseFunction2()
        .then((myRate) => {
        console.log('save array with postCounters AND myRate data')
      })
    })
  )
})
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log('the array with postCounters AND myRate data')
})
```

Things are getting wrong. The returned Promise.all doesn't wait until promiseFunction2 is run, so the second function is not working and im not getting the promiseFunction2 data inside my array, just the first.

What i think is happening is: Promise.all is getting after all promiseFunction is run, BUT it doesn't wait until the second function, i would like to wait BOTH to complete before getting promise all, should i use two Promise.all???

Im not very familiar with the syntax of Promise.all and im just using the promiseFunction().then() approach

(event to get my code consistent to scale well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use promise like this?!

```
let promises = [],
    promiseArr = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    promises.push(
        promiseFunction()
    );
});
Promise.all(promises).then((res) => {
    res.forEach(itm => {
        promiseArr.push(
            promiseFunction2()
        );
    });


    Promise.all(promiseArr).then((res) => {
        console.log('save array with postCounters AND myRate data');
    });

});
```

Comment: I want to merge both results in a single object.
promiseFunction() will return X, Y fields,
promieseFunction2() will return Z.
Each of them has to be merged into a array of objects with X, Y, Z fields, they have to be managed sequentially.
If i resolve them separately, i will get two separated arrays, i will have to make an extra third function to merge them in one. This can get even worse if i decide to add more information into the array

Comment: You can merge both result in a single object after 2 separate `promise.all` complete, before that you do not have second result

Comment: If you want do it asynchronous, I think you must write third function. Or do it sunchronous.

Comment: My structure is:
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            promiseFunction() .then((postCounters) => {
              promiseFunction2().then((myRate) => {
                    posts.push({
                      a: doc,
                      b: postCounters
                      c: myRate
                    })
                  })
              })

Im confused, because myRate and postCounters will be separeted arrays (i think)

Comment: Store first array of results in a variable (if you need global). in second promise which `myRate`s achieved, create your last objects.

Comment: Also you can change your function structures and call `promiseFunction2` in `promiseFunction` and implement your chains like this as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974370/working-with-array-of-promises-that-have-promises-inside/49976262#49976262 said

Answer (score 2):

You should use `map` to turn one array into another. The problem is that you're not returning the promise chain generated from promiseFunction2:

```
const promises = querySnapshot.map((doc) => (
  promiseFunction()
    .then((postCounters) => (
      promiseFunction2()
        .then((myRate) => {
        console.log('save array with postCounters AND myRate data')
      })
    ))
));
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log('the array with postCounters AND myRate data')
});
```

Or, for far less indentation noise, use `async/await`:

```
const promises = querySnapshot.map(async (doc) => {
  const postCounters = await promiseFunction();
  const myRate = await promiseFunction2();
  // do stuff with myRate
  console.log('save array with postCounters AND myRate data')
  // async functions automatically return promises that resolve when the block finishes
});
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log('the array with postCounters AND myRate data')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this way

```
let addQueue = q();

for (let i = 0; i < querySnapshot.length; i++){
 addQueue = addQueue.then(promisFunction.bind(null, querySnapshot[i]))
                        .then(function (r) {
                            console.log('OK: ', r);
                        })
}

function promisFunction(doc){
let deferred = q.defer();

promisFunction2().then((postCounters) =>{
and function for myRate 
deferred.resolve({ a: doc, b: postCounters c: myRate }) }
})
return deferred.promise//
}


 addQueue.then(function (result) {
                    console.log('your result is here');
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.

```
  let promises = []
  querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    promises.push(
      promiseFunction()
        .then((postCounters) => {
          return promiseFunction2();
        })
    )
  })
  Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you don't show why `promiseFunction2` needs to wait for `promiseFunction`. Neither of the functions are returning something so it's not clear what value you claim is missing.

If `promiseFunction2` needs to run after `promiseFunction` then you can do:

```
let promises = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
  promises.push(
    promiseFunction()
    .then((postCounters) => {
      return promiseFunction2()//missing return here
      .then((myRate) => {
          console.log('save array with postCounters AND myRate data');
          return [postCounters,myRate];//missing return here
      })
    })
  );
})
```

If you don't need to wait for `promiseFunction` to finish to start `promiseFunction2` then you can do:

```
let promises = [];
querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
  promises.push(
    Promise.all(
      promiseFunction(),
      promiseFunction2()
    )
  );
})
```

In both cases the result is an array of array:

```
Promise.all(promises)
.then(
  function(results){
    results.forEach(
      function(result){
        console.log("postCounters:",result[0]);
        console.log("myRate:",result[1]);
      }
    )
  }
)
```